# complex integration along real axis

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I am reading *P. Coleman's many-body physics book*. It gives a integral which is odd for me,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x - {\rm i}\alpha} =
{\rm i}\pi\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha),
\qquad \alpha \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
My question is how to calculate it. Sorry for my stupid question, at least it looks like.

Comment: this integral doesn't exists in the common sense, just as a principal value integral. This is because the integrals $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac1{x-i\alpha }dx$ and $\int_{-\infty }^0 \frac1{x-i\alpha }dx$ both diverge

Comment: If we understand the integral in the principal value sense as $\displaystyle I(\alpha)=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R\frac{dx}{x-i\alpha}$, it can be evaluated.
For $\alpha>0$ we close the contour in the upper half of complex plane. Denoting $I_R$ the integral along the half-circle of the radius $R$,
$$\oint=I(\alpha)+I_R=2\pi iRes_{z=i\alpha}\frac{1}{z-i\alpha}=2\pi i$$
and, leading $R\to\infty$,
$$I_R=\int_0^\pi\frac{iRe^{i\phi}d\phi}{Re^{i\phi}-i\alpha}\to\pi i\,\Rightarrow\,I(\alpha)=\pi i$$

Comment: For $\alpha$<0 we close the contour in the lower half-plane and integrate in the negative direction: $I(\alpha<0)=-\pi i$.
For $\alpha=0$ we can define the integral as $\lim_{R\to\infty}\lim_{r\to0}\int_{-R}^{-r}+\int_r^R$ and get zero.

Comment: @Svyatoslav why not put it into an answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a principal value, we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x:=&\lim_{R\to \infty }\int_{-R}^R \frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x\\=&\lim_{R\to \infty }(\log (R-i\alpha )-\log (-R-i\alpha ))\\
=&i\lim_{R\to \infty }(\arg(R-i\alpha )-\arg(-R-i\alpha ))
\end{align*}
$$

where I used that $\log z=\log|z|+i\arg(z)$. Now, by a simple trigonometric observation, we can see that
$$
\arg(R-i\alpha )-\arg(-R-i\alpha )=\begin{cases}
-2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arg(R-i\alpha )\right),&\alpha <0\\
2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arg(R-i\alpha )\right),&\alpha \geqslant 0
\end{cases}
$$
and that $\lim_{R\to \infty }\arg(R-i\alpha )=0$ for any chosen $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore
$$
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x=i\pi \operatorname{sign}(\alpha )
$$
∎

---

A more elementary approach is the following: just note that
$$
\int_{-R}^R \frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x=\int_{-R}^0 \frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x+\int_{0}^{R}\frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d z=-\int_{R}^0 \frac1{-x-i\alpha }\,d x+\int_{0}^{R}\frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d z\\
=\int_{0}^R \left[\frac1{x-i\alpha }-\frac1{x+i\alpha }\right]dx=\int_{0}^R \frac{2i\alpha }{x^2+\alpha ^2}dx
$$

Therefore
$$
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{2i\alpha }{x^2+\alpha ^2}dx
$$
Now the last integral can be easily computed, and it have the expected answer.∎

Answer (score 6):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x&=&\lim_{R\to \infty }\int_{-R}^R \frac1{x-i\alpha }\,d x\\&=&\lim_{R\to \infty }\int_{-R}^R \frac{x+i\alpha}{x^2+\alpha^2 }\,dx\\
&=&\lim_{R\to \infty }\left(\frac12\log(x^2+\alpha^2)-i\arctan\left(\frac x\alpha \right)\right)\Biggr|_{-R}^{R}\\
&=&\pi i \text{ sign}(\alpha).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Sorry, I can only choose one answer, through I like your answer most.

Comment: There is a typo: the last second line, first term should be log.